# Wait Statement error in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I read on bit adder in VHDL in Quartus II 9.1 from [this site](http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/labs/adder/add_tst.vhd). Firstly, according to guide I add and compile 1 bit adder - it works correctly.

```
-- Simulation Tutorial
-- 1-bit Adder

-- This is just to make a reference to some common things needed.
LIBRARY IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- We declare the 1-bit adder with the inputs and outputs
-- shown inside the port().
-- This will add two bits together(x,y), with a carry in(cin) and 
-- output the sum(sum) and a carry out(cout).
entity BIT_ADDER is
        port( a, b, cin         : in  STD_LOGIC;
              sum, cout         : out STD_LOGIC );
end BIT_ADDER;

-- This describes the functionality of the 1-BIT adder.
architecture BHV of BIT_ADDER is
begin

        -- Calculate the sum of the 1-BIT adder.
        sum <=  (not a and not b and cin) or
                        (not a and b and not cin) or
                        (a and not b and not cin) or
                        (a and b and cin);

        -- Calculates the carry out of the 1-BIT adder.
        cout <= (not a and b and cin) or
                        (a and not b and cin) or
                        (a and b and not cin) or
                        (a and b and cin);
end BHV;
```

when I compile it it works right. After that I add other VHDL to test that.
This is testbench of 1 bit adder:

```
-- ENGR 10 VHDL Lab
-- 1-bit Adder Testbench

-- A testbench is used to rigorously tests a design that you have made.
-- The output of the testbench should allow the designer to see if
-- the design worked.  The testbench should also report where the testbench
-- failed.

-- This is just to make a reference to some common things needed.
LIBRARY IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

-- Decare a testbench.  Notice that the testbench does not have any
-- input or output ports.
entity TEST_ADD is
end TEST_ADD;

-- Describes the functionality of the tesbench.
architecture TEST of TEST_ADD is 

    -- The object that we wish to test is declared as a component of 
    -- the test bench. Its functionality has already been described elsewhere.
    -- This simply describes what the object's inputs and outputs are, it
    -- does not actually create the object.
    component BIT_ADDER 
        port( a, b, cin         : in  STD_LOGIC;
            sum, cout         : out STD_LOGIC );
    end component;

    -- Specifies which description of the adder you will use.
    for U1: BIT_ADDER use entity WORK.BIT_ADDER(BHV);

    -- Create a set of signals which will be associated with both the inputs
    -- and outputs of the component that we wish to test.
    signal A_s, B_s : STD_LOGIC;
    signal CIN_s    : STD_LOGIC;
    signal SUM_s    : STD_LOGIC;
    signal COUT_s   : STD_LOGIC;

    -- This is where the testbench for the BIT_ADDER actually begins.   
    begin

    -- Create a 1-bit adder in the testbench.   
    -- The signals specified above are mapped to their appropriate
    -- roles in the 1-bit adder which we have created.
    U1: BIT_ADDER port map (A_s, B_s, CIN_s, SUM_s, COUT_s);

    -- The process is where the actual testing is done.
    process
    begin

        -- We are now going to set the inputs of the adder and test
        -- the outputs to verify the functionality of our 1-bit adder.

        -- Case 0 : 0+0 with carry in of 0.

        -- Set the signals for the inputs.
        A_s <= '0';
        B_s <= '0';
        CIN_s <= '0';

        -- Wait a short amount of time and then check to see if the 
        -- outputs are what they should be. If not, then report an error
        -- so that we will know there is a problem.
        wait for 10 ns;
        assert ( SUM_s = '0'  ) report "Failed Case 0 - SUM" severity error;
        assert ( COUT_s = '0' ) report "Failed Case 0 - COUT" severity error;
        wait for 40 ns;

        -- Carry out the same process outlined above for the other 7 cases.

        -- Case 1 : 0+0 with carry in of 1.
        A_s <= '0';
        B_s <= '0';
        CIN_s <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        assert ( SUM_s = '1'  ) report "Failed Case 1 - SUM" severity error;
        assert ( COUT_s = '0' ) report "Failed Case 1 - COUT" severity error;
        wait for 40 ns;

        -- Case 2 : 0+1 with carry in of 0.
        A_s <= '0';
        B_s <= '1';
        CIN_s <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        assert ( SUM_s = '1'  ) report "Failed Case 2 - SUM" severity error;
        assert ( COUT_s = '0' ) report "Failed Case 2 - COUT" severity error;
        wait for 40 ns;

        -- Case 3 : 0+1 with carry in of 1.
        A_s <= '0';
        B_s <= '1';
        CIN_s <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        assert ( SUM_s = '0'  ) report "Failed Case 3 - SUM" severity error;
        assert ( COUT_s = '1' ) report "Failed Case 3 - COUT" severity error;
        wait for 40 ns;

        -- Case 4 : 1+0 with carry in of 0.
        A_s <= '1';
        B_s <= '0';
        CIN_s <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        assert ( SUM_s = '1'  ) report "Failed Case 4 - SUM" severity error;
        assert ( COUT_s = '0' ) report "Failed Case 4 - COUT" severity error;
        wait for 40 ns;

        -- Case 5 : 1+0 with carry in of 1.
        A_s <= '1';
        B_s <= '0';
        CIN_s <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        assert ( SUM_s = '0'  ) report "Failed Case 5 - SUM" severity error;
        assert ( COUT_s = '1' ) report "Failed Case 5 - COUT" severity error;
        wait for 40 ns;

        -- Case 6 : 1+1 with carry in of 0.
        A_s <= '1';
        B_s <= '1';
        CIN_s <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        assert ( SUM_s = '0'  ) report "Failed Case 6 - SUM" severity error;
        assert ( COUT_s = '1' ) report "Failed Case 6 - COUT" severity error;
        wait for 40 ns;

        -- Case 7 : 1+1 with carry in of 1.
        A_s <= '1';
        B_s <= '1';
        CIN_s <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        assert ( SUM_s = '1'  ) report "Failed Case 7 - SUM" severity error;
        assert ( COUT_s = '1' ) report "Failed Case 7 - COUT" severity error;
        wait for 40 ns;

    end process;
END TEST;
```

but this error appears:

> Error (10533): VHDL Wait Statement error at add_test.vhd(65): Wait Statement must contain condition clause with UNTIL keyword

Comment: Are you trying to compile the testbench in the Quartus synthesis tool? That won't work, it's not synthesisable code. Compile it in a simulator, such as Modelsim Altera Edition, or ghdl.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank, I'm a beginer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Brian, Altera Quartus is a *synthesis* tool : it transforms your VHDL (or Verilog) code into a "netlist", that can be mapped onto actual gates (or Look-up tables in the case of FPGA, but that's another story). As such Quartus is like its concurrent ISE from Xilinx. There are other synthesizers, like Design Compiler from Synopsys, etc. In general you design in VHDL (or Verilog) for such purpose : getting a hardware that works at the end, on real gates (either FPGA or ASIC gates).

But prior to that, you also need to check that this circuit has chances to really work : for this you need a *test bench*. In general, this test bench is **not synthesizable** : it is just a set of processes that :

- generates all required clocks and reset
- feed your "design under test" (DUT) with data
- read back data after it has completed its own computation

Building a test bench is essentially a software discipline. The mentioned processes act as virtual instruments that put your DUT into expected conditions.